# "#REF!" appears in cell after referred-to cells are pasted in

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

On Office 2007's Excel on Win7, I have a file with a formula like `AVERAGE(A29:A33)` in cell A34.  I then copy four vertically-adjacent number-containing cells and paste them into cells A29:A33.  At this point, A34 now contains the formula `AVERAGE(#REF!)`, and then I have to re-input the formula, at which point it works fine.

How can I get A34's formula to be left alone when I paste into A29:A33 and simply calculate their average as I had intended that it do?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain the cells contain numbers (as opposed to text that looks like numbers, or formulas).

Comment: What's the content of the cells you pasted?  Maybe a paste special > values is needed?

Comment: @Paul, Yeah, they came from a tab-delimited txt import, so they're plain.

Comment: @ernie, The content is simple integers.

Comment: "four vertically-adjacent" means what?  What were the addresses for these four cells?

Comment: @ernie, it means exactly what it says...there are four of them, and each one is vertically adjacent to the next.  It's a 4-cell-high column.  Same shape as A29:A33.

Comment: The main problem with `#REF` problems is that, with simple cases, are hard (but trivial) to reproduce. I gave the explanation of why the `#REF` appears, but as I say here, there a several possible causes. The best bet is to paste values.

Answer (score 0):

You paste values, instead of the cell itself.

What happens is that, when simply pasting or drag-and-dropping, Excel loses the references it had to the cells. Have you ever noticed that, when dragging cells all around a worksheet, the formulas that depend on those cells never change (unless they depend on the locked cells, denoted by the `$` sign). Excel keeps internally the reference to those cells and as such, will lose them if you simply paste other cells.

If you however were to write (or, in this case, Paste Values) that would circumvent the problem.

Comment: Thanks, we'll give this a shot at next opportunity (I was asking on behalf of a friend who is now working on something else, and I don't have Excel on my own computer.)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to happen when you *cut* and paste cells, rather than *copy* and paste. Basically, if you copy, you're copying the values, but if you cut, you're moving the cells. Excel then effectively deletes the cells that were there originally, rendering the cell references in your formula useless. Try using copy rather than cut.

Alternatively, you could use `OFFSET` to give a relative reference to the cell containing your formula. But that seems a bit convoluted!